# Creating new instance without using type (class name) in Java

Tags: java, instance, new-operator

I found this code. Now I am puzzled what `origin = new Point(0, 0);` means. If it is instantiation/object creation where is the type (class name) preceding it? If it is an assignment why is `new` used?

```
public class Rectangle {
    public int width = 0;
    public int height = 0;
    public Point origin;

    //Four constructors
    public Rectangle() {
        origin = new Point(0, 0);
    }

    public Rectangle(Point p) {
        origin = p;
    }

    public Rectangle(int w, int h) {
        this(new Point(0, 0), w, h);
    }

    public Rectangle(Point p, int w, int h) {
        origin = p;
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    //A method for moving the rectangle
    public void move(int x, int y) {
        origin.x = x;
        origin.y = y;
    }

    //A method for computing the area of the rectangle
    public int area() {
        return width * height;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Point` is the name of a class.

Comment: `origin` is a field, declared 4 lines above the one that puzzles you.

Comment: @f1sh  Thanks I got it but what does this line do? Shouldn't it be  like `Point origin = new Point (0,0)`

Comment: @cs_student the line 4 lines above declares the variable `origin` as a member variable. In the line that puzzles you, that member variable gets a value.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question in the simplest way:

The line `origin = new Point(0, 0);` is basically setting the variable `origin` to a Point object with x and y both set to 0.
Now I think what you are confused on is why this is even there? First we need to look where it's declared. Every object has a constructor, whether it's an empty constructor of one that sets some variables to a default value (Like in this case!). In our case `origin` variable is being set to a default value inside the default constructor of the class Rectangle. Second the reason why we are doing this is because in Java you can declare an object without any arguments, when Java sees that no arguments are given, it will call the default constructor. In the default constructor it's highly recommended to define important variables that will be used in the object. I hope this helps! =)

Answer (score -1):

Point is type of variable. It basically stores two values(x and y). That's the simple explanation.

origin = new Point(0, 0) sets the value of the variable origin

the not so simple explanation is that Point is a class. origin is an object of that class and this line runs the constructor of this class that sets the value of the two variables in that object to 0 and 0

Comment: So variable origin has 2 values? Or how it is?

Comment: Basic java tutorial says that constructors initialize objects using following pattern `Point origin = new Point (0,0)` . But here we have `origin = new Point (0,0)`. Is it right?

Comment: Point origin = new Point (0,0) creates variable origin and in your case you create the variable earlier with the code public Point origin so you need to just set it's value. That's why you don't add Point in front.